# Как правильно сделать ссылки к css файлам?

Tags: php, html, css, link

Если домен такой: 
**site.com**
то можно прописать так:

```
<script src="http://site.com/asset/style.css"></script>
```

НО если юзер закинул архив сайта в подпапку, то этот вариант уже не подходит.

Можно прописать так:

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Будут такая ссылка:

```
<script src="http://site.com/подпапка/asset/style.css"></script>
```

Но если пользователь зайдет еще в одну папку, то уже и этот вариант не подходит, пример: [http://site.com/подпапка/admin/](http://site.com/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0/admin/) стили будут:

```
<script src="http://site.com/подпапка/admin/asset/style.css"></script>
```

а должно быть так:

```
<script src="http://site.com/подпапка/asset/style.css"></script>
```

Как правильно сделать, что бы ссылки работали и в папках и подпапках и т.д? К примеру в движке wordpress все работает как надо искал у них  коде не нашел как они это сделали, хочу так же сделать и у себя.

Comment: на странице указываете тег [`base`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/base), а все стили подгружаете по относительному пути

Comment: Относительные ссылки не катят? Вол втором варианте подставляйте только основной домен и не важноважно в папке или подпапке находится пользователь

Answer (score 1):

Задайте в конфиге своего движка переменную или установите константу равную url до папки сайта, например:

```
define('BASE_URL', 'http://site.com/подпапка/');
```

И там, где вам нужны абсолютные ссылки до файлов используйте ее, например:

```
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>asset/style.css"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

А зачем вы ссылки к стилям через тэги script объявляете? Ведь можно просто в `<head>` страницы написать `<link href="/asset/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` они и будут грузиться не зависимо от путей. Но это при условии, что `asset` лежит в корне